# Want to remove the highlighted heading when the current heading id clicked

Tags: jquery

Ive got this jquery code, ive figured out that when i click on the header it highlights red. My problem now is removing that highlighted color and only highlight the current or recent one that was clicked

```
$j('div.tabbed-sidebar ul.sidebar-tabs li a').click(function () {
        $j(this).css('background-color', 'red'); <---this is where is highlights red
        $j(this).removeClass('tab-current');
        var thisClass = this.className.substring(12, this.className.length);
        var parentId = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        $j('#' + parentId + '.tabbed-sidebar div.sidebar-tab-content').hide();
        $j('#' + parentId + '.tabbed-sidebar div.sidebar-tab-content-' + thisClass).show();
        $j('#' + parentId + '.tabbed-sidebar ul.sidebar-tabs li a').removeClass('tab-current');
        $j(this).addClass('tab-current');     
    });
```

Comment: Please, shrink you code to the relevant part, create a demo and explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/zENqJ/)

.js

```
$("h2").on("click",function(){
    $(this).addClass("red");
    $("h2").not(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

.css

```
.red{
    background: red;
}
```

.html

```
<h2>header</h2>
<h2>header</h2>
<h2>header</h2>
<h2>header</h2>
<h2>header</h2>
```